# How to rename filename to created_at Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

How to save filename to created_at ? Please help

```
        $fileName = $file->hashName();
        $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$fileName;
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath,file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a filename as timestamp, use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php):

```
$fileName = time();
```

If you want to use another format, in Laravel 5.5 you can do something like this:

```
$fileNmae = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
```

Comment: 1515573465 <- result please how to read that . it makes no sense for me :)   in current time here 4:39PM 2018/1/10

Comment: It's unix timestamp. You can read it with `Carbon::createFromTimestamp()`. If you want to use readable format, use the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's `$fileName` you want to rename - Using the syntax `rename(oldname,newname,context)` you could simply do something like `$oldname = $filename` and have `$newname` give you your desired `created_at` so that you can finally have `rename($oldname,$newname)`